# Move videos from Moodle 1.9 to Moodle 2.7

Tags: moodle

I have recently upgraded Moodle 1.9 to Moodle 2.7. After I upgraded to Moodle 2.7 the content (such as videos and PDFs) relating to a particular course are no longer working. When I upload content manually it works fine. Can you please tell me what I should do if I do not wish to upload the content manually as it is very time consuming.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 1.9 to 2.2 then to 2.7?

Comment: yes first upgrade from 1.9 to 2.2 then to 2.7

Comment: I can't tell you why it happens, but I can tell you that the best way to get around this error is to back up the course file, upgrade, and then import the course file as a new course in your 2.7.